# What's the simplest way to call a SOAP web service using a String for the request and response?

Tags: java, string, soap, integration-testing

I'm diagnosing an issue and would like to know the simplest way to call a SOAP web service. I'd like to setup a simple junit (integration) test that will hit a SOAP service. I have a SoapUI request working as intended, I'd like to take the URL and soap envelope XML request as a String from that, call it from a Java class and have the response as a String. I'm trying to avoid generating all of the objects/clients/etc usually involved with working with a SOAP service. I'm just looking for a quick and dirty way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can do just that. Post an xml body to the endpoint address. You can even use a template based on your envelope and change the parameters if required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following meets my needs:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(SERVICE_URL)
            .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), REQUEST_BODY))
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseBody = response.body().string();
```